# Probability kernel defined as quotient of integrals of joint density functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ have joint density function $f(x,y)$. For $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $A\in\mathcal{R}$, define
>   $$\mu(y,A)=\dfrac{\int_A f(x,y)dx}{\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)dx},$$
>   if $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)dx>0$ and $\mu(y,A)=0$ otherwise. Prove that $\mu$ is a probability kernel from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and that $X\mid Y \sim \mu(Y)$.

This was on a previous candidacy exam and I have no idea how to prove the result. I found out that it is a problem from [Durrett's "Probability: Theory and Examples"](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf), specifically problem 5.1.13. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Try going through Example 5.1.4 (which is what Durrett's book hints at when they say this is a continuation of that example) by taking the $g(x)$ as $\mathbb{1}_{x \in A}$.